# Which biblatex default citation style is the closest to these requirements and what is the proper way to implement them?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

In order to make it clear, I'll describe my citation style as a dichotomous tree. I think it's a kind of verbose-trad style (maybe `verbose-trad2` ?). As a french citation style, it makes use "op. cit", "ibid.", and "idem". I know that the `\ifciteibid`, `\ifciteidem`, `\ifciteseen` and `\ifsingletitle` will have to be used. The questions are:

- Which default `biblatex` citation style is the closest to mine ?
- What is the proper way to implement it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `verbose-trad2` comes closest to what you want.

Here is a start at implementing your decision tree based on that style.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=verbose-trad2,
  singletitle=true,
  ibidpage=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{titleopcitdelim}{\addcomma\space}

% suppress title if only only work by labelname
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \ifsingletitle
      {}
      {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
       \setunit{\printdelim{titleopcitdelim}}}%
    \bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

% idem also for full citations
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifnameidem}[1]{%
  \ifciteidem
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{#1}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\ifnameidem{author}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
          {\bibnamedash}
          {\printnames{author}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\ifnameidem{editor}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
          {\bibnamedash}
          {\printnames{editor}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\ifnameidem{translator}
       {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
          {\bibnamedash}
          {\printnames{translator}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
Lorem \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
Lorem \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
ipsum \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
ipsum \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
Lorem \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
Lorem \autocite[10]{nussbaum}
Lorem \autocite[10]{nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Many example citations.]

I've ignored citations with volumes for now as the solution there will depend on your input and will likely be more complex. I urge you to ask a new question with an MWE (possibly based on this answer) that shows what you have so far and how you cite these works and what the `.bib` entries look like.